# Phonegap - Scroll bar is not shown in phonegap application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm new in android. and i'm making an application in phonegap.
There is an list view on my first screen of the app.
The problem is that scrollbar is not shown in this as it will appear in android.

Any one can help me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. It will be helpfull to you.

```
    public class MyActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

         // Display vertical scrollbar and hide horizontal scrollBar
         super.appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
         super.appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // set scrollbar style
        super.appView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    }

}
```